# Step by Step sudoku solver in python

Tags: python, matrix, logic, sudoku

```
import sys
def main():
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
        s1 = f.read()
        s2 = s1.split()
        for i in range(len(s2)):
            s2[i] = int(s2[i])
        grid = [s2[i:i+9] for i in range(0, len(s2), 9)]
        solve(grid,0,0)

def check(grid, r, c, k):
    for i in range(9):
        if grid[r][i] == k:
            return False
        if grid[i][c] == k:
            return False

    x_area = (c // 3) * 3
    y_area = (r // 3) * 3

    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if grid[y_area + i][x_area + j] == k:
                return False

    return True

def solve(grid, r=0, c=0):
    f = open(sys.argv[2],'w')
    counter = 0
    if r == 9:
        return True
    elif c == 9:
        return solve(grid, r+1, 0)
    elif grid[r][c] != 0:
        return solve(grid, r, c+1)
    else:
        poss = []
        for k in range(1, 10):
            if check(grid, r, c, k):
                poss.append(k)
                if len(poss) == 1:
                    grid[r][c] = k
                    counter += 1
                    print("-" * 18, "Step " + str(counter) + " - " + str(poss[0]) + " @ " + "R" + str(r + 1) + "C" + str(c + 1), "-" * 18, sep='\n', file=f)
                    for x in grid:
                        print(" ".join(map(str, x)), file=f)
                    print("-" * 18, file=f)
                    if solve(grid, r, c+1):
                        return True
        return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In this code i take argument like this

0 4 0 0 0 0 1 7 9

0 0 2 0 0 8 0 5 4

0 0 6 0 0 5 0 0 8

0 8 0 0 7 0 9 1 0

0 5 0 0 9 0 0 3 0

0 1 9 0 6 0 0 4 0

3 0 0 4 0 0 7 0 0

5 7 0 1 0 0 2 0 0

9 2 8 0 0 0 0 6 0

then i turn this to list for indexing. I want to check cells and if there is a cell have one possible number to put number instead of zero, put this number and print all sudoku table then repeat this steps. print steps, solve again, print steps, solve again. But in my output.txt file it prints only first step. What is wrong?

------------------

Step 1 - 8 @ R1C1

------------------

8 4 0 0 0 0 1 7 9

0 0 2 0 0 8 0 5 4

0 0 6 0 0 5 0 0 8

0 8 0 0 7 0 9 1 0

0 5 0 0 9 0 0 3 0

0 1 9 0 6 0 0 4 0

3 0 0 4 0 0 7 0 0

5 7 0 1 0 0 2 0 0

9 2 8 0 0 0 0 6 0

------------------

This is output that i want but all steps like this. I mean there are 48 zero here and it have to print 48 step.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: *"if there is a cell have one possible number to put number instead of zero"*: you cannot expect that you can solve all Sudokus with that assumption. At some point there may be only empty cells that have *multiple* possibilities. What do you expect to happen then?

Comment: Its my homework and in this type hw expecting only basic sudokus. So I have to do that

Comment: But then the code you started from is not the right approach. There is no logic in your code that actively searches for a cell that only have one solution. It just takes the very first empty cell it finds and uses the first possible value that fits there.

Comment: is finding possible numbers and appends all of them in a list right way? Why didnt it work how can i fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues:

- Your output file will only have one grid, because in each call of `solve`, you call `f = open(sys.argv[2],'w')`. You should only open the file for writing once.
- You don't close the output file. Because of these two points, you need to wrap the recursive calls into a top-level call that opens and closes the file.
- The list `poss` is not of much use in the way you use it. It starts empty, and obviously after the first `append` it has one element, and so you place the value and make a recursive call. But this didn't really check whether the cell didn't have other solutions. Or if intended to do it the "backtracking way", if the recursion cannot solve the grid, then your code will not try an alternative. See next point.
- You write *"if there is a cell have one possible number to put number instead of zero"*, but this does not consider the case where there might be multiple possibilities for all cells that are empty (0). So that means you have to *try* a value, and if it doesn't lead to a solution, try an alternative, etc. If you really only want to fill cells that only have on possible value, you first need to let the `k` loop complete to the end, as only then you can be sure there is only one solution. And if that is not true, you should try with another cell, and not return `False`.
- Related to this, with proper backtracking, you need to backtrack when no value can make it to a solved grid. In that case you should clear the previously placed value, just before returning `False`. This also means that your output file may have many more outputs then just the number of zeroes, because it will also have outputs that later on turn out to not lead to a solution.

Here is the corrected code with a backtracking solution:

```
def main():
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
        s1 = f.read()
        s2 = s1.split()
        for i in range(len(s2)):
            s2[i] = int(s2[i])
        grid = [s2[i:i+9] for i in range(0, len(s2), 9)]
        solve(grid)  # call with one argument

def check(grid, r, c, k):
    for i in range(9):
        if grid[r][i] == k:
            return False
        if grid[i][c] == k:
            return False

    x_area = (c // 3) * 3
    y_area = (r // 3) * 3

    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if grid[y_area + i][x_area + j] == k:
                return False

    return True

def solve(grid):
    f = open(sys.argv[2],'w')  # Should only execute once. So not part of recursive function
    counter = 0   # Should only execute once. So not part of recursion.
    
    def recur(r, c):
        nonlocal counter
        if r == 9:
            return True
        elif c == 9:
            return recur(r+1, 0)
        elif grid[r][c] != 0:
            return recur(r, c+1)
        else:
            # Don't use poss. It will prevent you from trying all available options
            for k in range(1, 10):
                if check(grid, r, c, k):
                    grid[r][c] = k
                    counter += 1
                    print("-" * 18, 
                          "Step " + str(counter) + " - " + str(k) 
                                  + " @ " + "R" + str(r + 1) + "C" + str(c + 1), 
                          "-" * 18,
                          sep='\n', file=f)
                    for x in grid:
                        print(" ".join(map(str, x)), file=f)
                    print("-" * 18, file=f)
                    if recur(r, c+1):
                        return True
            grid[r][c] = 0  # backtrack!
            return False
            
    result = recur(0, 0)
    f.close()
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you are supposed to only solve cells that have just one possible value, then you better not use recursion, as there is no backtracking then. Use iteration:

- Find the next free cell and count the number of solutions it has. If one, then use that one. If not one, continue the search for such a cell. If no such cell is found, then the input puzzle is too complex for this algorithm (and you should use the above backtracking algorithm).

Here is the code for "simple" Sudokus:

```
def solve(grid):
    def count_empty_cells():
        count = 0
        for r in range(9):
            for c in range(9):
                if grid[r][c] == 0:
                    count +=1
        return count
        
    def find_cell_with_one_solution():
        for r in range(9):
            for c in range(9):
                if grid[r][c] == 0:
                    poss = []
                    for k in range(1, 10):
                        if check(grid, r, c, k):
                            poss.append(k)
                    if len(poss) == 1:
                        return r, c, poss[0]
        return None

    with open(sys.argv[2], 'w') as f:
        for counter in range(count_empty_cells()):
            result = find_cell_with_one_solution()
            if not result:  # could not find an empty cell with one solution
                f.close()
                raise ValueError("This is not a simple Sudoku puzzle!")
            r, c, k = result
            grid[r][c] = k
            print("-" * 18, 
                  "Step " + str(counter+1) + " - " + str(k) 
                          + " @ " + "R" + str(r + 1) + "C" + str(c + 1), 
                  "-" * 18,
                  sep='\n', file=f)
            for x in grid:
                print(" ".join(map(str, x)), file=f)
            print("-" * 18, file=f)
```

Comment: Thank you it gives true solutioun but there is a another problem about output. I have to print just true steps not turn back steps. I mean if there are 48 zero in sudoku i have to print only 48 step. Is there a way to do this

Comment: Sure, that is possible.

Comment: The reason i use poss is find the cell that have only one possible number to put in. I shouldnt use try everything way, i have to use logic-brutal force way

Comment: Can you help me about that solution I have been trying for one week and tomorrow is deadline, thank you

Comment: The you use poss is not helping you to find a cell that has only one possible number.

Comment: Added a version to my answer that only solves such simple Sudoku: it assumes there is always an empty cell that only has one possible value it can get, or else the grid should be full and solved.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: I am away from pc and when i try the code i am gonna reply, thank you

Comment: I just tried and it worked! Thank you so much